# Get Current Logged In User In Ajax

Tags: jquery, django, ajax

I Need to include a dynamic url in my ajax call which requires the current logged in user's username. How am I able to get this without adding it to a field on the button pressed (which I assume is bad practice) -> `<td class='complete' username='{{ request.user.username }}' student_id='{{ student.student.id }}' name='completed' value='{{ complete.id }}'>{{ item.completed }}</td>`.

I am using Django.

```
$(".complete").click(function(e){
    var csrfToken = $("input[name='csrfmiddlewaretoken']");

    checkbox_id = $(this).attr('value');
    student_id = $(this).attr('student_id');
    // gets id of clicked element
    var checked = $('#'+e.target.id).is(":checked");

    $.ajax({ url: "/teacher_hub/username/api/post_form/", // here, I need "username" to be dynamic
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        data: {'completed':checked, 'student_id':student_id, 'id':checkbox_id, 'csrfmiddlewaretoken':csrfToken.val()},
        cache: false
    }).done(function(data) {
        if (data.result === true){
            pass
            //alert(data.message);
        }
    });
});
```

Thank you.

Comment: Do you mean something like `"/teacher_hub/" + username + "/api/post_form/"`?

Comment: Exactly. I just don't know how to pass the username in to ajax without inserting it into the element clicked

Comment: So your problem is getting the value of `username`?

Comment: Yes, I need the variable ```username``` to be the value of the current logged in user's ```username```

Comment: Ok, there is only one problem: you have not described what the username is or what they are logging into

Comment: Haha sorry, can't believe I didn't include that. I just added it. I'm making the site with Django and am using Allauth authentication.